# How to add known words tokenizer keras python?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, data-science, tokenize

I want to convert text to sequence using keras with indonesian languages. but the keras tokenizer only detect the known word.

How to add known words in keras? or any solution for me to convert text to sequence?

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=n_most_common_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(concated['TITLE'].values)
txt = ["bisnis di indonesia sangat maju"]
seq = list(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences_generator(txt))
```

the "seq" variable resulting empty array if i used indonesian languages, its work perfectly if i used the english word. how to use keras for different languages? or anyway to add some known word to keras?

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce your example. Can you include the text your are using to fit the tokenizer? (concatenated['TITLE'].values). The language shouldn't matter for the tokenizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras doesn't *know* any languages or words. *You* create the vocabulary using the `fit_on_texts` or `fit_on_sequences` method.

I guess you are `fit`ting the tokenizer on some English text (i.e., `concated['TITLE'].values`). As a result, the internal vocabulary contains only English words (and no Indonesian words). This explains why `seq` will be empty if `txt` only contains non-English words.

Also, you can take a look at the [source code of the `Tokenizer` class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L138).

Comment: Thank you very much, my code work for now. yes it is the keras only know the word in fit_on_sequences.